# How can i increase default magento execution time in all format

Tags: magento-1.9, php, export, bug

I can't export my bulk products, both `system->import/export->export` and `system->import/export->data flow->` , both process not working properly, but when i export db from my server and export my root folder of magento `into` my local pc, install root folder and import db sql in wamp, right after i get export my products. Actually in my store 30,000 products are there,

> my export working only not working bulk export

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change the following value in your php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 18000
```

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini is for the PHP plugin used by Apache. This is the one you need to edit for changes to be applied for your Apache setup.

After that restart apache2

Comment: not working bro

Comment: Error :   http://i.imgur.com/zXvGefT.png

Comment: my .htaccess    http://i.imgur.com/8zt08XR.png

Comment: Does i did right ??

Comment: Your max_execution_time has been increased from 8048 to 18000.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: still not working http://i.imgur.com/S66Xr1b.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/S66Xr1b.png

Comment: @JeevaRathinam, did you restart your apache server after changed the time?

Comment: sudo service apache2 restart or sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

Go to Magento root Foder open your .htaccess file and increase the value of Below variable

`php_value max_execution_time 18000`

If it is already 18000 then increase TO 36000 save clear your cache and try again.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8zt08XR.png

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Then you need to increase your value from php.ini file in your server Because we cannot increase value more than php.ini file

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zXvGefT.png

Comment: my max_exe_time 18000

Comment: Increase in your php.ini file that is the solution

Comment: still not working      http://i.imgur.com/S66Xr1b.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/S66Xr1b.png